# Access - Combobox populated from another Combobox selects first item in list

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a combobox populated by the selection of another combobox, using Row source in the properties window..

```
SELECT DISTINCT tbl_PurchaseOrders.Customer, tbl_PurchaseOrders.[Customer Purchase Order Number] 
FROM tbl_PurchaseOrders 
WHERE (((tbl_PurchaseOrders.Customer)=[forms]![Qry_JobCard_Admin1]![Combo37])); UNION select distinct null, null FROM tbl_PurchaseOrders;
```

The list populates correclty, the problem is no matter what item is selected in the cobobox it defaults to the top item in the list...

Anyone any idea what would cause it?

Comment: Remove extraneous semi-colon in front of UNION and see what happens.

Comment: Why are you using UNION?